# Restart Activity when onSaveInstanceState event is fired

Tags: android, android-activity

I tried the following code to restart my activity when the user attempts to launch the home screen by pressing the home button.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state){
    try{
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LockerAppActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

There is no exception that occurs and the code fires. But the activity does not start. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step #1: Delete your `onSaveInstanceState()` implementation.

Step #2: Do not attempt to "restart [your] activity when the user attempts to launch the home screen by pressing the home button", because that is unnecessary.

Step #3: Fix whatever problems you think you are experiencing that are causing you to try this "restart" technique.

For example, given the class name `LockerAppActivity`, I am guessing that you are trying to create one of those easily-defeated "lock screens". Why you are bothering, considering anybody can get past them, is beyond me. Regardless, the proper way to ensure that your application runs when the user presses HOME is to be a home screen.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well, yes that is what I am trying to do. I am trying to create an application such that when it is launched, no other application on the device can be run. Meaning, this application is launched after device boot, and it is the only application allowed to run afterwards. Please not that this is not to be a standard consumer application, but rather a commercial application. How do you suggest I get about this ?

Comment: @HeshanPerera: "How do you suggest I get about this ?" -- as I indicated in the answer, make it be the home screen. It can still be removed by rebooting in safe mode; if you want to prevent *that*, you will need to root the device and/or install custom firmware.